# In Nifi, which is lighter on the system JSON or Avro?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to move some data from Postgresql database to SQLServer. For That I am using executesqlrecord, however I don't know which option is better, should I choose to write to a json or avro in the "Record Writer" property? and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are valid & efficient.

AVRO can be represented with a smaller binary format rather than just plaintext like JSON, meaning it can have a smaller footprint.

Unless you are working at very high throughputs, it won't make a world of difference. Pick the one that you are most familiar and comfortable working with.